# Opening relative URL is prefixed by two controllers

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a link from a razor (.cshtml) file where I call some jQuery through the onClick event:

```
...onclick="xxxx.forminstance.showFormInstanceNewTab(id);"....
```

The jQuery:

```
xxxx.forminstance.showFormInstanceNewTab = function (id) {
var url = 'FormInstance/ViewForm/' + id;
window.open(url, '_blank')    }
```

The above should then open the url `https://localhost/xxxx/FormInstance/ViewForm/'id'`

But instead it adds an extra Controller before the FormInstance, so the URL ends up being:

```
https://localhost/xxxx/FormPackage/FormInstance/ViewForm/'id'
```

which then results in an error. Why is the FormPackage being added? Where would this be defined/controlled? I can't give an absolute URL because the host will change in different situations.

Comment: Try perpending forward slash: `var url = '/FormInstance/ViewForm/'+ id;`

Comment: @Stephen Muecke: That will not work for web applications not at the domain root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that a relative URL (not absolute or root-relative) will be *relative to the current page*, so the browser prepends that part of the URL automatically to any relative links.

A common problem in ASP/MVC/Razor is requiring a site relative URL in jQuery code. Web applications may not be hosted off the domain root so you cannot just use *root-relative* paths (i.e. starting with `/`).

There are several techniques, but my favorite is to inject the site root into the page's `body` element:

e.g. in Razor syntax

```
<body data-root="@Url.Content("~/")">
```

Which will convert to:

```
<body data-root="http://localhost:1234/">
```

or (if your site is hosted as an application):

```
<body data-root="http://localhost:1234/applicationroot">
```

So you can then pick it up from jQuery using

```
 var root = $('body').data('root');
```

and then prepend that root url to any relative URLs

e.g. in your code:

```
var url = root + 'FormInstance/ViewForm/' + id;
```

I usually add a test after the `var root` to ensure my root URL always has a trailing `/`

Comment: Works like a charm and such a clean way to do it! Thanks.

Comment: @D.Singh: That's why I use it. Cleaner than injecting a Javascript variable value into pages (which is another option) :)